# Take the half of the year

Tags: r

Using data like this:

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), time = c("2020-11-04T13:29:30Z", "2016-10-30T21:10:39Z", "2019-03-30T21:10:39Z"))
```

How is it possible to create a new column which will show the first of the second half of the specific year?

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), time = c("2020-11-04T13:29:30Z", "2016-10-30T21:10:39Z", "2019-03-30T21:10:39Z"), timespand = c("2020-12","2016-12","2019-06"))
```

using 06 is the first half of the year and using 12 is the second half of the year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to month of the `time` column paste 6 or 12 to year value.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(time = ymd_hms(time), 
         timespand = paste(year(time), 
                     ifelse(month(time) > 6, '12', '06'), sep = '-'))

#  id                time timespand
#1  1 2020-11-04 13:29:30   2020-12
#2  2 2016-10-30 21:10:39   2016-12
#3  3 2019-03-30 21:10:39   2019-06
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `base R` to do this (`R 4.1.0`)

```
transform(df, time = as.POSIXct(time, format = '%FT%T'))|>
    transform(timespand =  sprintf('%s-%02d', format(time, '%Y'), 
         c(6, 12)[1  + (as.integer(format(time, '%m')) > 6)]))
```

-output

```
  id                time timespand
1  1 2020-11-04 13:29:30   2020-12
2  2 2016-10-30 21:10:39   2016-12
3  3 2019-03-30 21:10:39   2019-06
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another possibility using `substr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(half_year = paste(substr(time, 1, 4), 
                                  ifelse(as.numeric(substr(time, 6, 7)) > 6, "12","06"), 
                                  sep = "-"),
         time = ymd_hms(time), .keep="used")
```

Output:

```
                 time half_year
1 2020-11-04 13:29:30   2020-12
2 2016-10-30 21:10:39   2016-12
3 2019-03-30 21:10:39   2019-06
```